# Delete the user from the database after a while if not verified in laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, cron, conditional-statements

I would like to know if the registered users but their email has not been confirmed. Delete from the database.
example:

```
User::where('email_verified_at',null)->delete();
```

Comment: If you mean how/where you can do this, you may create a console command that does this by artisan make:command DeleteUnverifiedUsers, then schedule it to be executed once a day:
User::where(...)->where('created_at', '<', now()->subDays(2))->delete();

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in a function in kernel and use cronjob to check it automatically:

```
 $schedule->call(function () {

     $users=User::whereNull('email_verified_at')->delete();

})->hourly();
```

Comment: You don't need to loop the records, just call delete instead of get: `User::whereNull('email_verified_at')->delete();`